# outputting image with http handler

Tags: c#, httphandler

I have the following code for my handler I've debugged it and I can see that my image variable b has the actual image I need however I am not able to display it in my browser. When I run this I just get System.Drawing.Bitmap on the screen instead of the image. I am not sure how to write it to the browser.  Any ideas would be much appreciated it thanks.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://myaddress");
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
request.Method = "GET";
request.Accept = "image/jpeg";

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream s = response.GetResponseStream();
System.Drawing.Image b = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(s);
context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
context.Response.Write(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

Write it to the output stream:

```
b.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```